# Picture not loading with htm<Picture> tag

Tags: html, image

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<h2>The picture Element</h2>

<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_food.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_car.jpg">
  <img src="img_girl.jpg" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

I need to know if this is outdated and if you can insert local files

Comment: what do you mean outdated? The code looks fine. Do the images exist? What does the Developer Console of your browser tell ?

Comment: It's not outdated. Yes, you can insert local images. But the browser has to be able to find them (in this case, in the same folder as your HTML file). After you've checked that, if you still have problems, check your inspector.

Answer (score -1):

Your code references local images. This snippet is a clone of yours -- all I've done is change the images to web-accessible images. So your code is fine. If images are not appearing, it's because they can't be found.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<h2>The picture Element</h2>

<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="https://img.traveltriangle.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/cover-for-street-food-in-sydney.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2019-honda-civic-sedan-1558453497.jpg?crop=1xw:0.9997727789138833xh;center,top&resize=480:*">
  <img src="https://cdn2.momjunction.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/145-Best-Pretty-Girls-Quotes-1-624x702.jpg" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```